# Sections overlapping with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a bootstrap template and I'm having a problem.

The `section id="content-one"` shows up on the top of the page. It doesn't seem I can find a solution for this to place it under the full-screen header.

Needs to be positioned here:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzRqm.png)

Here is the code: http://codeply.com/go/8iYGenpntB

Comment: Not sure I follow. Your codeply link has #content-one in the same spot as your screenshot above. Did you want it somewhere else? http://imgur.com/8UuYPPf

Comment: Sorry. The #content-one needs to be placed below the main header. I was just pointing out his current pisition.

Comment: This is because your hero element is absolute positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that elements within `<section id="hero">` are absolute positioned, which take them out of the normal document flow and other elements will ignore their positioning on the page (i.e. pretend they're not there).  That is why `<section id="content-one">` is above the *"main header"*, i.e. `<section id="hero">` content. The elements that have absolute positioning are `.hero-wrapper` and `.hero-container`.

I'm not sure what the final layout should be or the requirements upon it so it's hard to recommend much beyond pointing out the source of the issue. You could possibly use padding and margin only to get `<section id="hero">` the height/size you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for your advicing words, I'm understanding the situation now. The idea is a "one-pager" with the main hero header resizing to different desktop screens. As soon as I change the "position: absolute;" the hero header doesn't cover the screen anymore to my screensize.